# Where not like in laravel mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

How to write **WHERE NOT LIKE** in laravel with mongodb ? I found this one but don't know how to use it in laravel -

```
db.tbl_users.find( { first_name: { $not: /^M.*/ } } )
```

Please help , thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the **[documentation](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)**:

The `regex` operator selects documents where values match a specified regular expression.

```
User::where('first_name', 'regex', new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex("/^M.*/"))->get();
```

**NOTE**: you can also use the Laravel `regexp` operations. These are a bit more flexible and will automatically convert your regular expression string to a `MongoDB\BSON\Regex` object.

```
User::where('first_name', 'regexp', '/^M.*/'))->get();
```

And the inverse:

```
User::where('first_name', 'not regexp', '/^M.*/'))->get();
```

Comment: Thank You @chridam , Big Help.